# User authentication in SOAP Webservices

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, ws-security

I made a question about [JAX-WS, Authentication and Authorization - How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314782/jax-ws-authentication-and-authorization-how-to); there was a discussion about security levels, and where to store user credentials.

Now after some conclusions, I want to try one of those scenarios:

- SOAP web services - metro
- Message level security - Mutual certificate authentication, to authenticate the client application
- User credential in the Soap Header

**How to get the credentials and do the authorization?**
I have 2 ideas:

- JAAS (I don't know anything about this);
- SOAP handler - using the WebServiceContext to extract the credentials from the message and do the authorization "by hand".

Can you help me to decide the best way, and how to implement it?

**Remember that I want mutual certificate, plus a user token.**

Comment: SAML and Single Sign On?

Comment: No. I thought about that. But had no need for something so complex. Just want the simplest way to do authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[JAAS](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jaas/tutorials/) does not define how the authentication information should look like in SOAP, but [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) defines what kind of standardized tokens you can use during client-server exchange (Username+password token / X.509 certificate / [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) token / [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) Token).

**EDIT:** With respect to [Metro](http://metro.java.net/) WebService stack, you need (steps taken from [here](http://mananvpanchal.blogspot.com/2010/06/jax-ws-webservice-with-plaintext.html) and [here](http://xwss.java.net/Securing_JAVASE6_WebServices.html)):

- Inject the handler, that implements `javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler` to JAX-WS handler chain either programmatically via `((BindingProvider)port).getBinding().setHandlerChain(Collections.singletonList(handler))` or declaratively by adding `@HandlerChain(file = "handlers.xml")` annotation to your WS endpoint interface.
- The handler should create `XWSSProcessor` instance using `XWSSProcessorFactory`, which is passed the callback handler that implements `javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler`.
- The callback handler e.g. defines a validator on callback (depends on callback type).

This is the same as "doing by hand" (as the 1st step is to intersect the SOAP message anyway), with some WSS sugar on top. But WSIT (and CXF) use JAAS API and they provide standard implementations for various authentication tokens. Enabling them needs some configuration / coding efforts, but the benefit is that if you later decide to switch from plainttext to Kerberos authentication, you don't need to code a lot. Also "doing by hand" means that you need to deal with authentication information on XML level and what you'll do is implementing one of the standards.

I suggest using [Apache CXF](http://61.153.44.88/apache/cxf/2.0/ws-security.html) that bases on [WSS4J](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j) – the WS-Security implementation from Apache. You can easily find tutorials (e.g. [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jws13/index.html) and [here](http://domagojtechtips.blogspot.com/2007/08/cxf-spring-and-ws-security-putting-it.html) for Username+password, [here](http://coheigea.blogspot.com/2011/04/saml-support-in-cxf-240.html) and [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-trust.html) for SAML) that show to define [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132600/passwordcallback-in-cxf) / interceptors to verify authentication information. The advantage of CXF is that it has nice integration with Spring.

Comment: @LuisP: Sorry, I have overlooked that. basically, the Metro stack is JAX-WS + JAXB + WSIT, which is very similar to CXF. If you wish, I can remove the answer, as it will be more fair in respect to bounty, but I will try to find some information for Metro (never used it). I feel that CXF provides better support for Spring than Metro.

Comment: that would be fair yes. if change it first, i will remove the -1. Please help me about metro if you can. I DON'T use Spring.

Comment: When searching for "pure Metro" solution I understood your question better :) Go with JAAS – that would be less bugs and better support.

Comment: One other thing that was not asked in the question, is there any restriction to the combinations of those tokens? I mean, Can I use x509 for the server x509 for client (Mutual certificate), and yet add a username+password token?

Comment: You'd better start a separate thread on that. I can't give an authoritative answer, but from my perspective nothing prevents this information to co-exist in header. The only small challenge will be to correctly chain your security handlers and define what kind of restriction do you need (x509 AND password / x509 OR password).