# EJB3 Based JAX-WS Web Service authentication on Weblogic

Tags: web-services, weblogic, ejb-3.0, jax-ws

I'm just trying to develop an internal web service for a news agency which is connected to a MySQL database where all the authentication/news data remains. The purpose of all of this is to generate an XML version of the article/ list of articles depending upon the client's subscription, so it can be shown by a mobile frontend that I am working on, using Java Server Faces.

Up to date, I have generated and annotated JPA entities from my database using Eclipse, as well as created a Stateless Session Bean so it can be published as a web service. All of this works absolutely fine, so it's time to take it to the next level, but I don't know where to start.
I managed to set up a custom authenticator provider within WebLogic using my database, but don't really know if that's handy and where to go next.
I also had a look on OpenAM but thought there should be something native to either JAX-WS or WebLogic.

How could I approach this? The requirements as far as I can see would be:

- One time authentication.
- Using username/password stored on a MySQL table.
- Authentication data provided within the SOAP message? (The client would log in through the JSF frontend, sending that data to the WS to check if it's valid).

Thanks!!!

p.s.: I did Java a long time ago, so I've been "disconnected" from the latest technologies/methodologies, so although my question goes quite straight to the point, if you think there would be a better way to accomplish what I've done so far just let me know, please.

Comment: You need to decide what kind of user/password authentication you want to apply. You can do it on HTTP level (check [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html)), or you can do it on SOAP level (check [User authenticate in SOAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766811)).