# JAX-WS session management

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have been trying to maintain user session in a standalone JAX-WS client. The server code is as explained in  https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2006/06/maintaining_ses.html.

My problem is with the client. The server does send the JSESSIONID with the response. But it looks like that the client's calls do not send the JSESSIONID with the request(I have tested this on TCPMon). Because of that the server creates a new session every time a request comes.

After some googling I found that I had to set BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY = true in request conext in order to maintain user session in client. But sadly this also is **NOT** working for me.

I have tried generating the stub using AXIS and the session here is being properly maintained.
The web service has been deployed in Tomcat.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't have sessions when using Webservices. A service should be an independent call to a system. In need for something like a session you can use some context data as header parameters.

Comment: Thanks lpinto.eu for your reply... Let me explain it a bit more... The web service I am trying to access has two operations viz. authenticate and getEmployeeDetails... Now the authenticate operation will authenticate the validity of the WS consumer. And the second operation will only work only if the client is authenticated. That is why the session came into picture. Is there a better approach? thanks

Comment: Are you using JAX-WS RI?  Or are you using CXF?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766811/user-authenticate-in-soap-how-to