# Java Web service security

Tags: java, security, web, service

I am working on implementing Java web service security .I am using Soap handlers .I need help with authenticating the username and password that received on provider side from the soap header. What does the provider side handler do.

Please do let me know if I am not clear or need more information.

Thanks
Niveditha

Comment: What is the help you are looking for? what have you done so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User authenticate in SOAP - How to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766811/user-authenticate-in-soap-how-to)

Comment: I have gone through some articles in this network and wrote the JAX-WS handler class that retrieves username and password from username token soap element .I am looking on how to authenticate this pair and send response back to client.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/