# Web service intranet call by web application java internet

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a web application java in internet and a web service (SOAP) in intranet. I need to call  only two of method web services..
What is the best way to do this? I have to guarantee the necessary security because the APPLICATION is on the internet but I can not allow free access to the intranet or access to the web service and all its methods. How to do it?
How do you invoke web services from the backend ?
HELP ME PLEASE.

Answer (score 0):

As i know SOAP allow you to use Statefull. [Some info](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40558)

So you can use JAAS for that, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766811/user-authenticate-in-soap-how-to?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)